# Get the text from a Text Field / Text View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I'm actually in big troubles on how to get the Text from a `TextField` (and optionally a `TextView` ).
I'll try to make it simple: I have my *PostIt.xib* which is composed of 2 labels (which I don't really care about) and also one `TextField` and one `TextView`. Here is how I tried to get the text from these:

First, in my `PostIt.h` :

```
@interface PostIt : UIView {
IBOutlet UITextField *titre;
IBOutlet UITextView *commentaire; }
```

Then secondly, in my `PostIt.m` : (the real action of this method is that it close a view and normally throw back the information I want to get to another view, here: `parent` )

```
-(IBAction)doubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
[_parent setTitre:titre.text];
[_parent setCommentaire:commentaire.text];
[_parent setIsEdited:true];
[self removeFromSuperview]; }
```

My problem here is, when I call a `NSLog` (for example) to show me the Strings which are caught (probably a mistake here? sorry) it show me every time : `(null)`

I have been looking and trying a lot of answer i found but no one seems to be able to solve my problem...
If someone could help me it will be really nice, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any more code pertaining to the `UITextField`?

Based on what I see here you need you first convert the input from the `UITextField` 
into a `string` and then you can set the `string` where you want.

**Updated to add the conversion code,**

```
NSString *stringFromTextField = [yourTextField text];
```

Here is some more details,

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *yourTextField;
@end
```

Your Action,

```
- (IBAction)yourAction:(id)sender {


   //Converting UItextfields into strings
NSString *stringFromTextField = [self.yourTextField text];
}
```

Here is a sample project I made for you on GitHub -
 [stringFromTextView](http://github.com/Ro4ch/textField-for-stockOverFlow-Answer)

Comment: So should I declare firstly a String like `String: value` then I need to convert the titre.text into a String to finally put it in value? How can I convert the input of my UITextField? Is there any method? Thanks :)

Comment: NSString *stringFromTextField = [yourTextField text];

if you are using properties then,

NSString *stringFromTextField = [_yourTextField text];

Comment: I tried: `NSString *stringFromTextField = [titre text];
    NSLog(@"stringFromTextField: %@", stringFromTextField);` <br/> But it's still getting me (null)... And it's not working with `[_titre text]`

Comment: set your textfield as a property 
NSString *stringFromTextField = [_yourTextField text]

Comment: So in my PostIt.h I wrote: 
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *titre; (which I've linked with the textField )   but it still giving me (null) with NSString *stringFromTextField = [_titre text]; ... I really dont understand why?

Comment: where are you putting you NSLog?

Comment: Juste after NSString *stringFromTextField = [self.titre text]; ---- But the problem could come from my PostIt.h? I wrote : "at"interface PostIt : UIView
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *titre; ---- is that correct ?

Comment: Look, here with a screen it could be better for you: https://gyazo.com/555182ee8f6147d1ed9c17e8cbe31401

Comment: go to interface builder and add a uitextfield. Now control drag it to your viewcontroller.m under @interface. Name that textField. Go to your IBAction and convert the textField into a NSString then call your NSLog line. Of course you will have to run the program and add characters to your textField and then do your IBAction.

Comment: Ok, just saw your screenShot. On quick glance that should work but make sure you are actually adding text to you textField before you execute your action.

Comment: It should work but it doesn't haha... 1st step: adding some shitty stuff in my text field (like: "this isn't working"), 2nd step: double tap, 3rd step: look at the beautiful NSLog: "stringFromTextField: (null)"... I'm lost :')

Comment: Here, I added this to github for you. I tested it and the NSLog returned the value from the textField - https://github.com/Ro4ch/textField-for-stockOverFlow-Answer

Comment: Hmmm. That's the same thing that I already have except that you're implementing *ViewController* and me *PostIt* in my .m file and your interface in the .h is *ViewController : UIViewController* and I have *PostIt : UIView*... Could the problem come from here? And should I do something with the delegate?

Comment: Could have something to do with your gesture. Put your code in a button and see what happens.

Comment: Right now you have it in a doubleTap gesture. I am suggesting you move that code to a uibutton to see if it works cause it could be something with the gesture.

Comment: So I've made it basically : - (IBAction)test:(id)sender {
    NSString *stringFromTextField = [self.titre text];
    NSLog(@"stringFromTextField: %@", stringFromTextField ); } with a button on my PostIt which is linked with this function but... After adding text or not in the TextView, the app crash with the message: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SelectPostIt test:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: please let me know what the problem was.

Comment: Ok I found it, thanks a lot guy <3, I had to link the TextView with his referencing outlet :p Your test said it to me :D

Answer (score 1):

You should try to input to your code an object part if that's not already done, where you could directly pick up the data that you need and that's also from here that you should update your view.